# Does js ever skip statements if outcome is already known?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console.log

Does javascript skip statements if the outcome is already known? I'm asking this because for some reason my code doesn't `console.log(b)` when the outcome is `alert('You Lose')`. It does console.log when the outcome is  `alert('You Win')`.

`C` always equals `true`.

So when `a = false` it does not `console.log(b)`, but when `a = true` it does `console.log(b)`

Why?

```
function example(c) {

var b = true;

    var a = validateFunction($('.div1'));    // returns true or false

    console.log(a);


    if (c === true) {  // c always equals true
        b = validateFunction($('.div2'));  // returns true or false
        console.log(b);
    }


    if (a === true && b === true) {
        alert('You Win');
    }
    else {
        alert('You Lose');
    }


}
```

Comment: What does validateFunction do? Your c variable isn't declared using the var keyword, which means it might be implicitly global, and be getting changed. Also, how are you calling the example function? If you are not passing in a variable, then it will have a value of undefined, which is falsy.

Comment: the validateFunction just does some math on some stuff, but just returns true or false.  Sorry about the c var part.. How i posted here isn't how i have it in my code. C always equals true for this.

Comment: From what I can see, your code will only execute `console.log(b)` if `c` is *strictly equal* to boolean `true`. It has nothing to do with any other variable value. What exactly is your question?

Comment: To answer the direct question: no, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that `c` is not === true. To verify, add an else clause to `if (c === true)` that contains something to the effect of `console.log('C is not === true.');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most languages parse if statements from left to right and stop as soon as they have a sure result.

Since your first expression in the if statement returns false, the whole statement can't return true, so it does not even try parsing it.

Same happens in an OR statement, if the first expression is false.

Comment: -1: You're talking about logic shortcuts - that has nothing to do with the question at hand.